# .gitlab-ci mysql service in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, gitlab-ci

I'm learning to use Gitlab CI and I'm trying to configure .gitlab-ci file to run CI into my Django project.

- I have the following .gitlab-ci file:

```
stages:
    - test
 
variables:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
    MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD

services:
    - mysql:8.0

test: 
    image: alpine:3.13
    stage: test
    script:
        - ...(up the app)...
```

- I have configured the environment variables in the gitlab (Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables), e.g:

[image]

I'm using 'mysql' as host. Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/mysql.html

- And I have the following DB configuration in my `settings.py` file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': getenv('DB_PORT'),
        'TEST' : {
            'NAME' : f"test_{getenv('DB_NAME')}",
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, all the installation is successfully but at moment to run test I have the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (-2)")
```

Why it happens if in Gitlab Documentation said that if I use the `mysql` services it's the host that I need to configure?

Comment: Sounds like `mysql` does not have a DNS record or entry in your /etc/hosts file.  Try using  what you think the IP address of your `mysql` server is.

Comment: Thanks for your help @RedCricket it was my fault. I've answered the question with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake. I read the logs - although they were extensive - and I've found the following lines:

```
2021-04-11T00:04:33.635793560Z     You need to specify one of the following:
2021-04-11T00:04:33.635798376Z     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
2021-04-11T00:04:33.635802359Z     - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
2021-04-11T00:04:33.635805957Z     - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

It's neccessary - of course - predefine the variable with the MySQL root password, without it the service can't run.

We need at least one of the following variables to run the service:

```
- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

I've changed my gitlab-ci file in the variables section and changed the directives by the following:

```
variables:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
    MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
    MYSQL_HOST: $DB_HOST
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

And then I've exported the `DB_ROOT_PASSWORD` variable inside CI/CD configuration (Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker (I suppose it from your DB_HOST), is your Mysql service called mysql? From the error you pasted, it seems like the django container (or wherever django is) can't resolve the hostname 'mysql'. If you are outside docker, maybe you have to configure mysql hostname in hosts file.

Comment: Yes. The Gitlab documentation says it. When you have a service called mysql, for example, it must resolve with the host `mysql` but it doesn't work.